# Error while communicating with API server using AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios, jdoodle

I've trying to communicate with JDoodle API Server using JavaScript (JQuery), but everytime it says, CORS error. But when I did the same using Java Servlets, it was perfectly working. I used axios, but it also says 'Network Error'.
My function looks like this:

```
function x()
        {
            var dataJ = {
                clientId: ''XXXXXXXXX,
                clientSecret:'XXXXXXXXXX',
                language:'PHP',
                script:'',
                versionIndex: '0'
            };
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/',
                data: dataJ,
                success: function(e)
                {
                    console.log(e);
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    console.log(e.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is controlled by backend API and in your case, you don't have control over it which is
`https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/`.

Browser prevents your code from accessing the response because the browser can't see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response.

Things can still get working by making the request through a Proxy can where a proxy sends appropriate CORS header on behalf of your request.

```js
const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/"; 
fetch(proxy + url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(contents => console.log(contents))
  .catch(() => console.log("CORS Error" + url ))
```

**For your case**

```js
const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/";

function x() {
  var dataJ = {
    clientId: "XXXXX",
    clientSecret: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    language: "PHP",
    script: "",
    versionIndex: "0"
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: proxy + url,
    data: dataJ,
    success: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e.statusText);
    }
  });
}
```

Making a request through a proxy will work this way

1. CORS proxy will forward your request to `https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/`
2. The return response from `https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute/` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.
3. Now your browser can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers present in the response header.

For more detail explanation you can check out this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/2850383

Comment: Sir, your explanation was outstanding and idea was interesting too, but it still doesn't work for me... it returns Unsupported Media Type... No idea about it!!!

Comment: Sorry, it's done... I forgot to add content-type header in the request.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its a security policy that dont let to other client use a site functionality:

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

only page of that site can send message to site or that site active allow-access-allow-origin on own site